# How to remove an ambari service after they have been added

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform

After you add a service to a node, how do you go about removing that service from say one node or all nodes?

For example, I have added pig and now I have decided that I no longer want pig installed on any of my nodes. Do I have to go into each node and manually do a `yum remove pig` to remove pig from my nodes?

Ambari makes things really easy to add but not so easy to figure out how to remove

Answer (score 5):

You can try to delete a host component by using the Ambari REST API as described on this website:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Using+APIs+to+delete+a+service+or+all+host+components+on+a+host

Answer (score 3):

In Ambari Web (or via Ambari REST API), you can remove components from a host (or a host entirely). Browse to the Hosts page, click on a host and then next to each component (in the Actions menu) you have a delete option. Note: ambari doesn't run "yum erase" or remove on packages though. It focuses on making sure Ambari does not manage that component any longer, and that the component is not considered part of the cluster. Packages remain on the machines.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled through this for longer than a while and then decided to share it here:

The trick is to basically delete all the symlinks pointing back to locations where HDP components reside since that is what causes 80% of the problem. Here is a step by step tutorial for that:

http://www.yourtechchick.com/hadoop/how-to-completely-remove-and-uninstall-hdp-components-hadoop-uninstall-on-linux-system/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl command like :

```
curl -u admin:admin -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X DELETE \
           http://AMBARISERVER:8080/api/v1/clusters/CLUSTERNAME/hosts/NODENAME/host_components/CLIENTNAME
```

Answer (score -1):

I have found a hack for this freaking Ambari 1.7 to remove a component which is added but not installed fully. You have to remove the infected/half-cooked component from PostgreSQL db.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can only lead to bigger problems down the road. Would not recommend.